# Return; как оно должно работать в cmd?

Tags: c#, c, консоль

У меня есть проблема. Не могу найти никакой информации о команде `return`. Вернее найти не могу ту информацию, которую ищу. Как сделать, чтобы эта команда возвращала на предыдущее действие в программе.

Чтобы было понятнее. Я делаю викторину для командной строки и мне нужно, чтобы при неправильном ответе человека возвращало на предыдущую страницу.

Comment: Хм. Это ваша первая программа? Я бы посоветовал для начала почитать (любую) книгу и разобраться, как работают основные конструкции языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return возвращает данные из функции или метода, а не возвращает на определенную стоку кода :)

```
public static string CreateFio(string surname, string name, string otchestvo)
        {
            string fio = surname + " " + name + " " + otchestvo;
            return fio;
        }

string name = "Александр";
string otchestvo = "Сергеевич";
string surname = "Пушкин";

System.Console.WriteLine(CreateFio(surname, name, otchestvo));
```

Выведет: Пушкин Александр Сергеевич

Comment: @WorldCount: Если `name` и `surname`, то тогда `patronymic`, а не `otchestvo`.

Comment: @VladD код не мой, взял для примера)